# How is my jgplot plotting previous data after updating the series array?

Tags: javascript, plot

So I have a pretty simple script, but it seems, somehow that on page load, the script runs, but the WHILE Loop is NOT executing (I don't receive the alerts). If I call the script a second time the WHILE Loop runs. Any idea why it would not run on page load but then run on a second call?

```js
function buildProfile(titleText){

alert("buildProfile Script is running, titleText variable was passed as " + titleText);

var profileSeries = [],
 profileArr = [],
 count = 0,
 size = 840;

while (count < size){
 profileArr[count] = ProfileData.DataValue("CmNameProfile.PROFILEA.DATAARRAY[" + count + "]");
 count++;
 if (count < 2){
  alert("While Loop Started");
  };
 if (count > 839){
  alert("While Loop Finished");
  };
 };

alert("While Loop Complete? If so this value should be in the proper range for profile selected. The value is " + profileArr[50]);

profileSeries.push(profileArr);

var optionsObj = {
 title:titleText,
 axes:{xaxis:{min:0, max:840}},
 seriesDefaults:{color:'#00ff00', lineWidth:2, showMarker:false},
 grid:{background:'#000000', gridLineColor:'#aaaaaa', shadow:false},
 canvasOverlay:{show:true, objects:[{horizontalLine:{name:'setpoint', y:15, lineWidth:2, color:'#ffffff', shadow:false}}]}
};

plot1 = $.jqplot('plotDiv', profileSeries, optionsObj).replot();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up setting a 1 Second delay on my function and it appears to be executing perfectly on every call now (including on initial page load). For this project, this will suffice for now. :)